# How to modify the video format after the download in swift

Tags: json, swift, file-manager

I have a problem in modifying the video format after downloading from videoplayback to mp4 and save to camera.

This is my download code, but I downloaded some video with a different format example : "videoplayback". I can't save to camera because I want to change format video to mp4.

[image]

```
func SessionDownload(URLSession : String) {
    MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: view, animated: true)

    let hud =  MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    // Set the bar determinate mode to show task progress.
    progress = 0.0
    hud?.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.determinateHorizontalBar
    hud?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    hud?.labelText = NSLocalizedString("Downloading...", comment: "HUD loading title")
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {() -> Void in
        // Do something useful in the background and update the HUD periodically.
        self.doSomeWorkWithProgress()
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
            //hud?.hide(true)
            hud?.labelText = NSLocalizedString("Just Wait...", comment: "HUD loading title")
        })
    })



    let videoPath = URLSession
    print(videoPath)

    let s = videoPath
    let url = NSURL(string:s)!
    let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url as URL)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let task = self.session.downloadTask(with: req as URLRequest)
    self.task = task
    task.resume()

}

//MARK:- share video
func doSomeWorkWithProgress() {
    // This just increases the progress indicator in a loop.
    while progress < 1.0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

            print(self.progress)
            MBProgressHUD(for: self.view).progress = self.progress
        })
        usleep(50000)
    }
}

//MARK:- URL Session delegat
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    print("downloaded \(100*totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
    taskTotalBytesWritten = Int(totalBytesWritten)
    taskTotalBytesExpectedToWrite = Int(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    percentageWritten = Float(taskTotalBytesWritten) / Float(taskTotalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    print(percentageWritten)

    let x = String(format:"%.2f", percentageWritten)
    print(x)
    self.progress = Float(x)!
    print(progress)

}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didResumeAtOffset fileOffset: Int64, expectedTotalBytes: Int64) {
    // unused in this example
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    print("completed: error: \(error)")
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("Finished downloading!")
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    // this can be a class variable
    let directoryURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]


    print(directoryURL)
    let docDirectoryURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(directoryURL)")
    print(docDirectoryURL)


    //Save To Photos
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL:directoryURL)
    }) { saved, error in
        if saved {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }



    let destinationFilename = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent
    print(destinationFilename!)
    // append that to your base directory
    let destinationURL =  docDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(destinationFilename!)")
    print(destinationURL!)
    /* check if the file exists, if so remove it. */
    if let path = destinationURL?.path {
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path) {
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(at: destinationURL!)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }

        }
    }

    do
    {
        try fileManager.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationURL!)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error while copy file")

    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    })
    // let videoLink = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let objectsToShare = [destinationURL!] //comment!, imageData!, myWebsite!]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare , applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.setValue("Video", forKey: "subject")
    //New Excluded Activities Code
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop, UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivity.ActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivity.ActivityType.mail, UIActivity.ActivityType.message, UIActivity.ActivityType.openInIBooks, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivity.ActivityType.print]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop, UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivity.ActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivity.ActivityType.mail, UIActivity.ActivityType.message, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivity.ActivityType.print ]
    }
    if let popoverController = activityVC.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = self.BtnDownloadVideo
        popoverController.sourceRect = self.BtnDownloadVideo.bounds

    }
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy and paste the message from the console and post is as text into your question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and they are harder to post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when you download a file from the internet, you are sure you are downloading a video in this circumstance? And what you are really wanting is just to change the format, i.e. `PathExtension` such as .mp4, .png, jpeg, etc.

Iff (if and only if) this is the case, then you can add a file extension on to the path component.

```
let destinationURL = docDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(destinationFilename!)").appendingPathExtension("mp4")
```

Now, when you check your saved files, it will include the ".mp4"

Again, I'm assuming you are 110% confident you are downloading a ".mp4" from the interwebs.